# Is QuickVPN Secure

Tags: vpn, ipsec

Does QuickVPN create a secure tunnel or how does it work to provide encryption and security?

When I did a see my IP it was using the remote locations IP and not my office network's IP so does that mean there is no tunnel? Is it safe?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: *yes, connections to your office are safe; but probably only those are, while Internet surfing still isn't.*

> When I did a see my IP it was using the remote locations IP and not my office network's IP so does that mean there is no tunnel? Is it safe?

What you observed depends probably on your configuration. The VPN stuff works by creating a "virtual network interface" that gets traffic from your PC and forwards it through an encrypted tunnel, just as if you were connected by a *really* long cable to the VPN server.

Problem is, your *normal* network interface is not deactivated (it couldn't be. Encrypted packets go through *that*).

So how does your system know where to send which packets? It does by using *routes*. Your virtual network interface advertises a route for *some* packets, those on your protected network. So if you try to connect to, say, 192.168.0.123, the system sees that those IPs have to be reached through 172.20.17.1, which goes through the VPN.

*But* if the default route is still set to your provider's, then *all* other packets (including those directed to the Whats-Your-IP-Today web server - will not be encrypted and they will go through the "normal" connection, which usually is a desirable thing since it saves VPN bandwidth for sensitive connections.

If you want *all* your traffic [*except the one towards the VPN server, making up the VPN tunnel itself...*] to be routed through the VPN, you need to change its configuration.

Actually, I googled "QuickVPN" since not all VPN implementations are the same, and found [this guy](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21574975-Re-VPN-QuickVPN-confusion) with a **LinkSys QuickVPN** and your same woes, to which he got this answer:

> The symptom you see is is because the Linksys QuickVPN client by design is a split tunnel as described by jza80.
>
> Perhaps there is a way to configure the Linksys QuickVPN client to do a transparent tunnel, but I am not aware of a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

it works like a regular VPN... QuickVPN name is just a name it doesnt mean it is a lite version of VPN that doesn't work as good as regular VPNs...

It gives you option to encrypt your traffic, if you set your traffic to be encrypted, it will be pretty secure and I am not sure but assuming default is encrypted.

If you IP is resolving as the remote locations IP, than there is a tunnel and your packets are being passed by the tunnel and than go to internet. As if you are working in a intranet and reaching the internet via remote location.